# Why Scoped service in Blazor server App will not create new instance to each device?

Tags: blazor, scoped

I use core 6 and initiate a class named DAL as a scoped service in blazor server app.

Instead of creating new DAL instance to each connected device it uses the same instance to all of the devices.
I tested it in debug mode and it actually hit the `services.AddScoped<DAL>();` line only once.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

**Startup.cs**

```
 [Obsolete]
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //This command is for API route
    services.AddMvc(setupAction: Options => Options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
    services.AddScoped<DAL>();
    services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

}
```

**_Host.cshtml**

```
 <app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
</app>
```

Comment: `AddScoped` creates an instance of the DAL service for each connection or circuit. The DAL service is scoped to the circuit lifetime... Run your app, and apply some changes that should modify a state in your service. If this is an issue, just define a primitive variable and assign it a given value when your app is running. Now open a new tab, type the url to your app, and then access the variable and verify wether its value is the same. If it's the same, you're right as each tab you open is a new instance of your app (a different device, right),

Comment: and thus, must have a new instance of the DAL service. If they are different, that means that your claim is baseless. If they are the same, you'll have to provide a reproduciable code of your program.

Answer (score 0):

As per @enet's comments - I don't believe this.

The simplest way of testing this is is to assign a GUID to each instance of `DAL`.

Here's my Blazor Server version.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public class DAL
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    //....

    public DAL()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DAL Service Id created {Id.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

As expected I get a new Id for each browser window opened, which is the same as each device!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found the problem.
It was related to my DAL class architecture and how I used it in my razor pages.

Comment: It's better to delete the question, neither it nor this answer will ever help anyone else.

Comment: I tried it won’t allow me. Sorry…